# Is it possible to set the buffer size of pipes when using asyncio subprocesses?

Tags: python, buffering

I'm writing a rather complex script that is using

```
asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(sub_cmd, *sub_cmd_args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

to wrap around another Python program -- that I can't modify permanently or otherwise include directly -- to capture its stdout/err for logging.  The wrapped Python script is not using the `-u` (unbuffered) option so the wrapper program tends to log in big buffered blocks.  If this were the regular subprocess.Popen I could just pass `bufsize=1` to get what I want, namely line buffering.  However if I add that to asyncio.create_subprocess_exec() they trap for that specifically and I get:

```
<snip>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/asyncio/subprocess.py", line 193, in create_subprocess_exec
    stderr=stderr, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in subprocess_exec
    raise ValueError("bufsize must be 0")
ValueError: bufsize must be 0
```

I assume their trap is there for good reason so I wonder if there's some other way I can affect the transport buffering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I first proved to myself that this was a indeed a pipe buffering issue by adding `-u` to the wrapped program's shebang line.  I couldn't rely on that as a solution though because such a change would eventually get clobbered by OS updates.

I was able to resolve the issue though in a similar fashion though:

- The wrapper program is the parent program of the pipe, so it controls the environment of its child programs.
- Python should obey the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` in its inherited environment.
- `asyncio.create_subprocess_exec()` does support an `env=` argument and most everything else that can be passed to `subprocess.Popen()`; perhaps a little under-documented but looking at the code makes this quite obvious.

So I changed my call to:

```
asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(sub_cmd, *sub_cmd_args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, env={'PYTHONUNBUFFERED': '1'})
```

This worked perfectly and credit goes to my good friend and technical guru.